# using docker image in travis ci (w/o Dockerfile or building a container)

Tags: docker, travis-ci, gitlab-ci

### TL;DR

So long story short: what is the right way to translate such a multi-image gitlab-CI file to travis-CI? Especially a way that allows the script to be more complex than bare commands.

### long version

With gitlab CI one can run different CI jobs in different docker images with next to no knowledge about the docker CLI and docker files like this:

```
build_jessie-gcc48:
  image: debian:jessie
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y git cmake g\+\+-4.8 ninja-build
  script:
    - BUILDDIR=$(mktemp -d)
    - cd ${BUILDDIR}
    - SOMEVAR=somevalue cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-4.8 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-4.8 ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}
    - cmake --build builddir

build_stretch-gcc63:
  image: debian:stretch
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y git cmake g\+\+-6 ninja-build
  script:
    - BUILDDIR=$(mktemp -d)
    - cd ${BUILDDIR}
    - cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-6 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-6 ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}
    - cmake --build .
```

I.e. my script is mostly normal shell code, I can `cd` and assign/use variables. I'm wondering how to do the same with travis. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133107/travis-ci-docker-image-as-build-environment) post suggests using the docker CLI, but there are a few things I find inconvenient about that approach:

- learning to use the CLI, assigning names to the different images which bring complexety where it's not needed.
- Adding `docker exec IMAGENAME` to every line clutters the yml
- Using variables adds another layer of resolving them (should variables get resolved inside or outside the docker image?)
- Changing directory with `cd` does not "just work" (it's a shell builtin and not an executable, right?
- One needs to re-clone or mount the checked out repository

So my current approach looks something like this:

```
language: c++
services:
  - docker

jobs:
  include:
    - script:
      - docker pull debian:jessie
      - docker run -itd --name JESSIE -v ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}:/repo.git debian:jessie
      - docker exec JESSIE apt-get update
      - docker exec JESSIE apt-get install -y git cmake g\+\+-4.8 ninja-build
      - docker exec JESSIE bash -c 'cd $(mktemp -d) && \
                                    SOMEVAR=somevalue cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-4.8 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-4.8 /repo.git && \
                                    cmake --build .'
    - script:
      - docker pull debian:stretch
      - docker run -itd --name STRETCH -v ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}:/repo.git debian:stretch
      - docker exec STRETCH apt-get update
      - docker exec STRETCH apt-get install -y git cmake g\+\+-6 ninja-build
      - docker exec STRETCH bash -c 'cd $(mktemp -d) && \
                                     cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-6 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-6 /repo.git && \
                                     cmake --build .'
```

This involved some try&error because `bash -c apt-get` didn't succeed because `apt-get` was unknown to bash(?). (And this job even fails because the variable assignment leads to an error from bash `SOMEVAR=somevalue command not found`, and `cmake` isn't found although it just got installed). So I generally don't have the impression that this is how this is meant to be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why the `SOMEVAR=somevalue` didn't work because the syntax looks fine and should be compatible with `docker exec CONTAINER bash -c '…'`

Anyway, I have a proposition for writing your `.travis.yml` that would be less verbose and closer to the phrasing of the GitLab CI conf file: it relies on the so-called [block style](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#style/block/) of YAML.

All steps are run within the same bash command, so you will be able to assign variables and reuse them.

Here is the corresponding `.travis.yml` I would suggest:

```
sudo: required

language: cpp

services:
  - docker

jobs:
  include:
    - script: |
        docker run --name JESSIE -it -v ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}:/repo.git debian:jessie /bin/bash -c '
        export PS4='\''+ \e[33;1m($0 @ line $LINENO) \$\e[0m '\'' # quotes must be escaped
        set -e # exit on failure
        set -x # trace for debug
        apt-get update
        apt-get install -y git cmake g\+\+-4.8 ninja-build
        cd $(mktemp -d)
        SOMEVAR=somevalue cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-4.8 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-4.8 /repo.git
        cmake --build .'
    - script: |
        docker run --name STRETCH -it -v ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}:/repo.git debian:stretch /bin/bash -c '
        export PS4='\''+ \e[33;1m($0 @ line $LINENO) \$\e[0m '\'' # quotes must be escaped
        TRAVIS_EVENT_TYPE="$1"
        set -e # exit on failure
        set -x # trace for debug
        echo "Build triggered by ${TRAVIS_EVENT_TYPE}"
        apt-get update
        apt-get install -y git cmake g\+\+-6 ninja-build
        cd $(mktemp -d)
        cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-6 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-6 /repo.git
        cmake --build .' bash "${TRAVIS_EVENT_TYPE}"
```

A few related remarks:

- As advised by the [doc](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/), I added `sudo: required` (and replaced c++ with cpp).
- The single quotes `'` are mandatory at the end of the first and last lines of the script.
- I removed the `docker pull debian:jessie` command because it should be automatically triggered by `docker run […] debian:jessie […]`
- Using a bind mount (by passing the option `-v ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}:/repo.git`) is a good idea!
- You can also pass the `--rm` flag to `docker run` if you want to remove the container right away after the tests (unless you want to inspect or reuse the container in a subsequent Travis CI command). If you pass the `--rm` flag, you should of course remove the `--name JESSIE` option.
- I removed the `-d` flag because now it's unneeded to run the container in the background as there is only one `docker run` and no `docker exec`. Also, it ensures that the output of the Bash commands passed to `docker run` will show up in Travis CI logs (since they don't run in the background).
- The Bash option `set -e` is recommended in such a CI context, while the option `set -x` is less crucial (it could be replaced with `set -v` for a similar purpose with less verbosity), and the line redefining `PS4` is useful to get an improved yellow prompt with `set -x`. Also, note that both `-e` and `-x` options can be directly passed to bash if you want (i.e., you can replace `bash -c 'set -e; […]'` with `bash -e -c '[…]'`).
- Finally I modified the second script to exemplify how one can pass additional variables (here, the Travis CI env variable `TRAVIS_EVENT_TYPE`) from Travis to the Docker/Bash context.
  Actually, a simpler way to achieve this consists in using option `-e`:

  ```
  docker run […] -e TRAVIS_EVENT_TYPE="${TRAVIS_EVENT_TYPE}" debian:jessie /bin/bash […]
  ```

Note: I didn't test this solution myself because I don't have a `cmake` project by hand; but if you have some feedback or see an issue with this proposition, feel free to let me know.

Comment: @pseyfert have you already had the opportunity to test this approach?
(FYI I have just added two examples regarding env var passing)

Comment: I think your example is almost complete. The problem I see with it now is that in case of a failure I hardly see where the error happened: https://travis-ci.org/pseyfert/CI-analogy-playground/jobs/375922562 and also this example failed in travis but worked in gitlab-ci https://gitlab.com/pseyfert/CI-analogy-playground/-/jobs/66895088

Comment: @pseyfert thanks for your feedback :) but it seems that the issues you encounter are just due to the fact you didn't follow exactly my suggestion, regarding the use of YAML blocks. FYI I wrote a [small test calling a python3 script that fails](https://github.com/erikmd/docker-travis-demo/blob/master/.travis.yml) and it appears that with your phrasing (`script:\n-` instead of `script: |\n`) I confirm that there is no output, but [the job unexpectedly succeeds](https://travis-ci.com/erikmd/docker-travis-demo/jobs/122762349).

Comment: @pseyfert Regarding the output, I took the opportunity to add a small yellow prompt to increase readability (I updated the SO answer and an output exemple is shown in [this job](https://travis-ci.com/erikmd/docker-travis-demo/jobs/122762348)), which script section thus uses YAML block style. Finally note that another upside of this style is that *you can also insert Bash comments in the Travis CI script*. (But of course, to get `'` inside the `'`s, which is needed by my custom `PS4`, you have to escape them by writing `'\''` instead.)

Comment: @pseyfert just an unrelated minor remark regarding the scripts: you don't need sudo because you are root in the docker container ;)